# how use textarea input for post

Tags: php, post

use the input tag to send the data. I need a bigger area to write the comment, but how to make the comment in the textarea to be sent when the button is pressed?

```
 <form action="action.php" method="post">

 <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>your comment:<textarea name="comment" >Enter text here...</textarea></p>

 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

the second part

```
name:    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
comment: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']); ?>.
```

Comment: what is the error? and second thing why you casting `comment` to integer

Comment: The same way as with the `<input>`  remove the `(int)` there's no way a text area can be off an int datatype

Comment: Set in id for the textarea (ex: id="comment") and then use $_POST['comment']

Comment: @Sfili_81 php does not read ID property

Comment: @user2938 after edit are you still struggling?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp2\htdocs\action.php on line 5

Comment: You can't use `textarea` directly, you can use `input` type and make the textbox larger using css

Comment: for textarea it can read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the `(int)`
2. Add rows and columns parameters to textarea
3. Add name to submit button
4. Add condition `if (isset($_POST['submitbutton']))`

My code for this question:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">

 <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>your comment:<textarea name="comment" rows="HEIGHT" cols="WIDTH">Enter text here...</textarea></p>
 <p><input type="submit" name="submitbutton"/></p>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitbutton']))
{
    echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']);
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```